# Drawing on grid board

Tags: vb.net

Im doing conway's game of life program. My board is two dimensional array filled with objects stated as alive or not. Im drawing board with:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim cellSize As Size = New Size(10, 10)

    For x As Integer = 1 To board_width - 1
        For y As Integer = 1 To board_height - 1

            Dim cellLocation As Point = New Point(x * cellSize.Width - 10, y * cellSize.Height - 10)

            Dim cell As Rectangle = New Rectangle(cellLocation, cellSize)

            Using cellBrush As SolidBrush = If(board(x, y).alive, New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(cellBrush, cell)
            End Using
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Im changing state of one cell by clicking on board.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    pic_pos.X = ((e.X - 5) / 10) + 1
    pic_pos.Y = ((e.Y - 5) / 10) + 1
    board(pic_pos.X, pic_pos.Y).alive = Not board(pic_pos.X, pic_pos.Y).alive
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Now i want to continuously change state of cells by clicking and holding mouse button(like drawing in paint) and i dont know completely how to do it. Any help or suggestions ? 
ps sorry for bad english

Comment: Your X and Y doesn't cover the entire surface of your board : the first row of cells on the top, and the first column of cells on the left. When you'll launch your game of life, those cells won't be updated... And also, with `((e.X - 5) / 10)`, you wont be able to compile your code if you set `Option Strict On`.. use "\" instead, the vb.net counterpart for Div (integer division)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the MouseMove event, check for which button was pressed, and make sure your point is still within the bounds of your array:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
  PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
  If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
    pic_pos.X = ((e.X - 5) / 10) + 1
    pic_pos.Y = ((e.Y - 5) / 10) + 1
    If pic_pos.X >= 0 And pic_pos.X < board_width AndAlso _
       pic_pos.Y >= 0 And pic_pos.Y < board_width Then
      board(pic_pos.X, pic_pos.Y).alive = True
      PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```